# Compare two Timestamps Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, timestamp

I am trying to count the amount of notifications a user has got in Codeigniter. I am comparing the timestamp that is saved in each users row that records when they last checked the notifications page and the time added for each notification. However I am getting a database error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10:17:00' at line 5

SELECT * FROM (`notifications`) WHERE `user_id` = '1' AND `instigator_id` != '1' AND added <= 2014-11-04 10:17:00
```

Filename: /Users/true/Documents/Site/models/private/notifications_model.php

Line Number: 152

The Notifications controller looks like this

```
$data["user"] = $CI->Profile_model->get_public_profile_id($logged_user);
$count = $CI->notifications_model->get_notifications_count($data["user"][0]["notes_check"]);
```

The model:

```
public function get_notifications_count($time){


    $this->db->from($this->notifications_table);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata("id", 0)); 
    $this->db->where('instigator_id !=', $this->session->userdata("id", 0));
    $this->db->where('added <= '.$time, '', false); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $results = $query->result_array();

    return count($results);
}
```

Comment: Strings need to be encapsulated in quotes, always

Comment: @MonkeyZeusTried with $this->db->where('added <= '."$time", '', false);  and still getting an error

Comment: Have you read the documentation? `$this->db->where('some_field' , 'some value');`

Answer (score 0):

Your date/time values are strings. Since you don't have `'`-quotes around them, MySQL is seeing this:

```
added <= 2014-11-04 10:17:00
         ^^^^^^^^^^---mathematical subtraction = 1999
                   ^^^^^^^^^--illegal unknown field/table name
```

It should be

```
added <= '2014-11-04 10:17:00'
```

Note the quotes.